# Increase validTill time for Custom Cache manager in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, caching

I am using CachedNetWorkImage with flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.2
I have set the stale period to 5 minutes

```
  static const key = 'customCacheKey';
  static CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
    Config(
      key,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(minutes: 5),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 200,
      fileService: HttpFileService(),
    ),
  );
}
```

and set CachedNetworkImage to use my LocalCacheManager like

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
             cacheManager: LocalCacheManager.instance,
             imageUrl: model.business.companyLogo,
             imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 shape: BoxShape.circle,
                 image: DecorationImage(
                     image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
               ),
             ),
             errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset("assets/images/apple_icon.jpg"),
           ),
```

but upon inspecting the File info for current image I still see the valid info till 7 days.
How do I increase or decrease the valid till time of the image file.

Today is 2021-27-05 and valid till date is 2021-06-03
[image]